# What's the memory usage of LINQ Join?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, memory

1. If the two IEnumerable(s) are in memory, what would be the memory usage for joining them? Assume selecting all columns. Is it size of left table + size of right table + number of rows in the joined table?
2. If the two IEnumerable(s) are defined by file streaming, will Join throw out of memory exception if they are too big to fit in memory? Or will it load until near out of memory and run the scans multiple times (similar to database join)?

Comment: Why not try it and find out? It probably "depends", like most things in the world. It certainly depends on which LINQ provider is being used.

Comment: I'm curious why you're asking. Why does the memory usage of a join matter?

Comment: When you say "Join," do you mean "Union" (all rows of A followed by all rows of B, like the `JoinIterator` method) or do you mean the linq/database-style "Inner/Outer Join" (combine rows of A and B into a single row based on key fields)?

Comment: I meant Enumerable.Join(), e.g. Inner Join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking in Reflector at `Enumerable.JoinIterator`, it seems that the whole `inner` (second) sequence is loaded into memory (into a `Lookup`), but that the `outer` (first) sequence is then streamed (i.e. *not* all loaded into memory).

There doesn't seem to be anything clever going on if the `inner` sequence is too big to fit into memory.

[Jon Skeets seems to agree on the first point](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join.aspx):

> The real Join operator uses the same behaviour as Except and Intersect when it comes to how the input sequences are consumed:
>
> ...
>
> - When MoveNext is called on the result sequence for the first time, it immediately consumes the whole of the inner sequence, buffering it.
> - The outer sequence is streamed - it's only read one element at a time. By the time the result sequence has started yielding results from the second element of outer, it's forgotten about the first element.